# Shell Script to move file from Server A to Server B everyday at a scheduled time

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ftp

Can anybody throw some lights on how to create a shell script to copy or move a file from /storage/file/ on Server A to /hdd/file location on Server B everyday at 11:30am automatically.We were using Filezilla and Windows File transfer tool like winSCP to get such task done before, now we got this need.Any help, idea or even a conversation on this topic would be really helpful

Comment: Have you tried `scp`? `rsync`? `sshfs`? Filezilla?

Comment: I've used filezilla, not the other tools that u've mentioned & filezilla works good. But for this case, we need the solution to be a unix script or a command.

Comment: @mac_online So one "server" is actually a "client", right? When you write "two servers", it give an impression that you need to run the script on 3rd machine. While it actually seem to want to run the script on one machine, connecting to the other.

Comment: Sorry, that's right Server A is the client.We have all the passwords needed to connect, but unfortunately there's no keyless connection established as of yet. The script has to run from A.

Comment: @mac_online So please edit the question accordingly. Though I'm pretty sure, now that your question is that trivial, that this must have been asked here dozen times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two Linux servers, you can simply write a bash script using `scp` to export the data from one server to another one, and run this script  every day with a cron job.

`scp` command:

```
scp -r -p link/to/source/file user@serveur2:link/to/destination/file
```

Cron line:

```
30 11  * *  * username scp -r -p link/to/source/file user@serveur2:link/to/destination/file
```

Comment: Let me try your solution.

Comment: Just to add, you will need to set up ssh-keys if you are running this as a cron job.

Comment: There are some authentication barriers in between. I think we have to manually type in the password everytime Server A try to connect to Server B.

Comment: If the authentication is only on your server B, you need to set up ssh-key.